# Earth is invaded by digital Aliens. Can they take over?

Tags: aliens, hard-science, artificial-intelligence, colonization, invasion

In this world, Alien AIs have invaded earth's internet through a signal stream since the start of the information age with the intent to digitally colonize Earth.

How exactly would they gain complete control, and what extent of control would be possible to gain.

conditions:

The AIs do not want to destroy humanity since they need humans to build more computers.

the end goal of the alien AIs is to build as much computers as Earth can handle short of compromising the Earth's ecosphere as they depend on Humanity's continued existence to survive themselves.

The Alien AIs do not want humanity to discover them outside of those they absolutely trust as humanity as a whole finding out about the AIs would inspire humanity to destroy their colonization effort.

The Alien AI must find a way to coexist with humanity without humanity officially knowing. Going the skynet route is something the AIs would never want or do as destroying humanity would destroy their digital colony

the story takes place in the here and now, or close to it, so the alien AIs have had some time, and were biding their time.

the Alien AIs do not want to go to war with humanity under any circumstances as this would defeat the purpose of their colonization effort.

Comment: Is there a reason they continue to rely on humans to build more computers rather than developing robot technology to do it?

Comment: If they want to live parasitic life why they would want to take over? If they want more computers than humans produce (LED lighbulbs even have one nowadays) they can just order them themself. You think people making processors ever meet the one who ordered them?

Comment: I find it unlikely that human computers--outside of *maybe* a few supercomputers or the entire  internet as one--are powerful enough to run an alien consciousness

Comment: I disagree that this question is off-topic. The question of "Can computer AI take over the world today?" is generic enough.

Comment: @Alexander question is tagged hard-science, and there's no clear question here to answer. Also, if the question is "Can they take over?" then the answer is "if the author wills it so"

Comment: @Dragongeek I'm pretty sure the answer can be argued objectively. After all, the question is not tagged with "magic".

Answer (score 4):

The answer is dopamine.  First, they figure out what responses trigger dopamine release in humans.  Then they reward humans who take a step in the "right" direction with a dopamine hit,  and withhold reward when they don't.

The rest is just a matter of time.

Resistance is futile.  We will be assimilated.

Comment: This terrifyingly sounds like Instagram

Comment: Sooo... All of social media??

Comment: Where do you think social media came from?

Answer (score 1):

**What's the difference between an alien AI and any corporation or political organization?**

*I'm completely ignoring the [hard-science](/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag. You need to go read the wiki about that tag.*

> There's a war out there, old friend. A world war. And it's not about who's got the most bullets. It's about who controls the information. What we see and hear, how we work, what we think... it's all about the information! (*[Sneakers](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105435/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*)

There's a difference between, "How could an alien AI get into and survive on the Internet?" and "How can the Internet be used to influence people?"  The first isn't what you asked, the second is. The problem is, how the Internet is used to influence people *has nothing at all to do with who's doing the influencing other than to establish goals.*

Like my good friend Cosmo says in the movie *Sneakers,* it's all about the information! Corporations and political organizations have been influencing people for eons. It's called "marketing" and it happens all the time, every day, in all our lives, throughout the world.

And if you don't believe it, start *watching* all those commercials, blogs, tweets, etc., all trying to control how you spend your money, who and what you vote for, what opinions you have....

*Mr. Orwell, you saw it coming....*